# Генерация qrcode

Tags: php, qrcode

Как можно сгенерировать на php qrcode биткоин по его адресу, например для этого? 15v3Wm3sDUht2VtgtLyvUxdcTw6pAwGaA5?

типо такого

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: первая ссылка в гугле: http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/

Comment: делаю так,
<?php
include('assets/phpqrcode/qrlib.php');
$param = '15v3Wm3sDUht2VtgtLyvUxdcTw6pAwGaD3';  // здесь не хватает защиты от вредоносного кода
echo QRcode::png($param); // генерируем qr-код и выводим напрямую как png-поток
 но в итоге выдает вот что - �PNG

���
IHDR���o���o����#���PLTE������U��~��IDAT8��ӱ�� �o��,�-�
�p���@�g��fwO{���t�C��?��O\�(���Q9B�Fѩ��|%���ѩ�����T��ƒ��>���7��|�u��n�
M���n/]D�M|�>n�;]�!O��G�9�z��Up2�i�e���H�KRd*q�U�!rt�F�r���FO�4<$ܜ�eB?

Comment: Добавь перед echo вызов header('Content-Type: image/png');

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include "phpqrcode/qrlib.php";
QRcode::png("2MwkjH5EgUHZ6Gm3aoWvaW7BWyWSHMgy6nX");
```